# Image from FTP not getting displayed on HTML page in asp.net core

Tags: html, asp.net

i have made a page in HTML and i want to display some images on that page which are placed on FTP folder the method i am using is

```
<img src="ftp://ftp_user:password@XXX.XXX.XX.XX/Folder/image.jpg"/>
```

but image not getting displayed. Please help!
Top

Comment: First of all, if you do that, everybody can see the password. Is the FTP folder on the same server?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, brother.

The correct address should be "https://ftpserver.com/folder/file.png" and the ftp server should also be linked to the main server or alias.

Now the files are displayed without entering the username and password in the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="https://servername/Folder/image.jpg"/>
```

please insert here domain link not ftp details